# Automated way of deleting millions of rows from Postgres tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, automation

Postgres Version: `PostgreSQL 10.9 (Ubuntu 10.9-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit`

Before I ask my question, I would like to explain why I'm looking into this. we have a history table which has more than 5 million rows and growing every hour.

As the table length grows the select queries are becoming slower, even though we have a proper index. So ideally the first choice for us to delete the old records which are unused.

**Approach #1**

We tried deleting the records from the table using simple `delete from table_name where created_date > certain_date where is_active = false`

- This took a very long time.

**Approach #2**

Create a script which would delete the rows with the cursor-based approach.

- This also takes a very long time.

**Approach #3**

- Created a new unlogged table.
- Create an index on the new_table.
- Copy the contents from the old table to a new table
- Then set table is logged.
- Rename the master table as a backup.
- Issues with this approach, it requires some downtime.

On live productions instances, this would result in missing data / resulting in failures

**Approach #4**

On further investigation, the performant way to delete unused rows is if we create a table with partition https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html - Which we could drop the entire partition immediately.

Questions with the above approach are

1. How can I create a partition on the existing table?
2. Will that require downtime?
3. How can we configure Postgres to create partition automatically, we can't really create partitions manually everyday right?

Any other approaches are also welcome, the thing is I really want this to be automated than manual because I would extend this to multiple tables.

Please let me know your thoughts, which would very helpful

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we are using `PostgreSQL 10.9 (Ubuntu 10.9-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry changed the link to 10 link. But the questions remain the same.

Comment: If partitioning on the date, you have to define a level of chronological granularity that fits your use case be it a year, a quarter, or a month. Your partitioning function/index will push your data into the correct partition. You can then switch out the oldest partition with a new partition either by script or manually. I will say that 5 million records is not a huge amount. Perhaps you are missing a covering index for one of the queries being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for approach 4, table partitioning.

1. Create partitions
2. New data goes directly to the correct partition
3. Move old data (manually / scripted) to the correct partition
4. Set a cron job to create partitions for the next X days, if they don't exists already

No downtime needed

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Frank Heikens. So just to confirm I can create table partitions without the downtime and so I can create partition every month once and have cron worker drop the old partitions which become completely unused. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how we do it. We have always at least 3 partitions for future months, just in case the cron job fails and we fail to spot this issue. It's now January, that means we have already Februari, March and April 2021 available. January the 28th, the next partition will be created, May 2021. September 2020 will be deleted the 28th, we don't need that partition anymore.

Comment: Thank you once again. So how does this cron work? Is this part of Postgres or do you separate script running with microservice? Do you maintain the already creation partitions somewhere ? or using exist query will take care of that? more curious. :)

Comment: It's a single Linux cron job executing a SQL script using the psql-client. That SQL script does a lot of things and works fine. It also generates output, so we can check in the morning for anomalies.

Comment: Hey but it seems like there is downtime needed for creating a partition on non-partitioned existing table https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106014/how-to-partition-existing-table-in-postgres

Comment: That's a question from 5 years ago, and I think even then you didn't need downtime. Maybe a lock for half a millisecond, but I don't consider that "downtime".

Answer (score 1):

> We tried deleting the records from the table using simple `delete from table_name where created_date > certain_date where is_active = false`  This took a very long time.

Surely you mean `<`, not `>` there?  So what if it took a long time?  How fast do you need it to be?  Did it cause problems?  How much data were you trying to delete at once?

5 millions rows is pretty small.  I probably wouldn't use partitioning in the first place on something that size.

There is no easy and transparent way to migrate to having partitioned data if you don't already have it.  The easiest way is to have a bit of downtime as you populate the new table.

If you do want to partition, your partitioning scheme would have to include is_active, not just created_date.  And by day seems way too fine, you could do it by month and pre-create a few years worth up front.

Answer (score 0):

Answering specifically to  the below:

> How can we configure Postgres to create partition automatically, we can't really create partitions manually everyday right?

As you are using Postgres 10, you could use https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman for auto management of partitions.